Is the following summation manipulation allowed?
Will it be logically incorrect to make the following manipulation?
$$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty f(n)\cdot\ln(n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n+1)\cdot\ln(n+1)$$
where $f(x)$ is diverging, or $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$. I'm a high schooler just learning series and not sure if such a manipulation is allowed.

Yes it's allowed. What you actually did is, you substituted $n$ as $r+1$
When $n=2$ then $r+1=2$ or $r=1$ similarly when $n=\infty$ then $r+1=\infty$ or $r=\infty$
So the expression becomes,
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty 
f(r+1)\cdot\ln(r+1)$$
Now you just have to replace $r$ by $n$ as both are nothing but variables.
